# PHP can't receive data sent using jquery . lead to undifined variable on php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send data from a HTML `select` to a PHP file using jQuery. Unfortunately it does not work. I have looked at all the solutions proposed here and it's still not working. Here is the code:

```
<select id="city" name="city" >
    <optgroup label="Popular Cities">
        <option selected style="display:none;color:#eee;">Entire country</option>
        <option value="city1">city 1</option>
        <option value="city2">city 2</option>
        <option value="city3">city3</option>
        <option value="city4">city4</option>
        <option value="city5">city5</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#city").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'post.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { city: $(this).val() },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            window.location.replace("post.php");
            window.location.reload("post.php");
        }
    });
});
```

```php
$city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : false;
echo "".$city."";
```

The `alert()` works but I still have no data received in `post.php`. I have tried with the code below as well but still can't have it.

```
$.post("post.php", { city: $(this).value }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
    window.location.reload("post.php");
    window.location.replace("post.php");
});
```

Any help?

Comment: What happens (or doesn't) in post.php? Does the alert return the city written?

Comment: Remove the `window.location...` lines. They're entirely redundant when using AJAX.

Comment: problem is in data sent or recieve?

Comment: yes the alert returns the city name , but post can't echo. php displays a undefined variable city so  i think its data sent .

Comment: you mean you want to sent city name again on the post.php file?

Comment: yes want to sent city name to post.php. not again the second ajax code is another way of doing the same thing

Comment: or just want to send city name on selection?

Comment: Then no need to use ajax, you need to wrap selectbox in a form and submit form with get method on city selection from jquery

Comment: Is this clear to you?

Comment: Tell me otherwise I will post answer.

Comment: i tried that before , but i need to submit before it posts , so can't the city  name unless i add a submit button but i don't want that .

Comment: Does your alert shows selected city name?

Comment: yes and it works now with @DeepakDholiyan solution below  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use form for this as said in comments

```
<form action="post.php" method="get" id="frmForm">
 <select id="city" name="city" >
<optgroup label="Popular Cities">
    <option selected style="display:none;color:#eee;">Entire   country</option>
    <option value="city1">city 1</option>
    <option value="city2">city 2</option>
    <option value="city3">city3</option>
    <option value="city4">city4</option>
    <option value="city5">city5</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Then use jquery to submit form on city selection

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#city").change(function() {
$('#frmForm').submit();    

});
```

Then you can find city name with $_GET['city'];

Answer (score 0):

It's not how you're meant to use Ajax. What your PHP file should be doing would be to handle the data sent in the Ajax request, and return a content which will be handled by the Ajax success callback.

What you're trying to do here is to:

1. Post data to `post.php`, which is working fine,
2. Then, go on `post.php`, which doesn't have the data previously sent, since you're making a completly new HTTP request.

What you should be doing would be to submit the form when your `select` changes, which would redirect you to `post.php` using HTML, not JavaScript.

Comment: See the answer from Deepak Dholiyan.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this suits what you want:

HTML file:

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
<select id="city" name="city" >
    <optgroup label="Popular Cities">
        <option selected style="display:none;color:#eee;">Entire country</option>
        <option value="city1">city 1</option>
        <option value="city2">city 2</option>
        <option value="city3">city3</option>
        <option value="city4">city4</option>
        <option value="city5">city5</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Then in post.php have the same code as current.